# Understanding how declval is working in the copy_assignment situation

Tags: c++, c++11

I was watching Dr. Walter E. Brown's Template Meta-programming talk. In his presentation he presents code like so for `is_copy_assignable`:

```
template<class U, class = decltype(declval<U&>() = declval<U const&>())>
static true_type try_assignment(U &&);
```

What I am having trouble with is how is the assignment operator being called in this instance. When I try and reason about this code and say substitute a dummy type, say `int`, in place of the `U` I get:

`template<class U, class = decltype(declval<int&>() = declval<int const&>())>`
`template<class U, class = decltype(int& = int const&)>`

So I am wondering then how can this help us determine if the assignment operator is valid. If I understand `declval` correctly this code will not even evaluate so then how can one determine from `int& = int const&`, which doesn't even evaluate, if there is or isn't a assignment operator defined for `U`.

I understand that in most cases the copy-assignment operator would be defined as

```
C& operator=(const C& other)
```

which looks a lot like what is above, but still since nothing is being evaluated then what use is this information.

Comment: Why did you turn `declval<int&>()` into `int&`?  What do you think `declval<int&>()` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really follow what you intended in performing the following step:

```
template<class U, class = decltype(declval<int&>() = declval<int const&>())>
template<class U, class = decltype(int& = int const&)>
```

`declval` says: pretend to return a *value* of type of the template argument. I say pretend because the function isn't really defined, only declared, so it can only be used in an unevaluated context. Inside of `decltype` is an unevaluated contexts because you're only checking types.

So, the expression `decltype(declval<int&>() = declval<int const&>())` is basically saying: if I had an `int&`, call it `x`, and I had a `int const&`, call it `y`, what is the type of the expression `x = y`?

As you can probably guess this calls the assignment operator and this expression will have a valid type (in this case, `int&`). If you change `int` to `unique_ptr`, this expression won't have a valid type, because `unique_ptr` is not assignable, causing type substitution to fail and eliminating this template from the overload or specialization set.

The reason to have declval at all is because it lets you create a value of any type; this is particularly useful for a) creating something of reference type, and b) creating non-reference types without assuming that they have e.g. a default constructor. Thus, use of `declval` is extremely ubiquitous in high quality TMP.

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstanding what `declval` actually was doing. Its pretending to return the value which of the type which is what I wasn't picking up on.